# pygame instalado no puede funcionar desde el IDE

Tags: pygame, python-3.8

Estoy tratando de aprender pygame por lo cual, por supuesto, lo instalé.

Ahora bien, para comenzar a entender el paquete quiero usar este sencillo código:

```
import sys
import pygame

# Inicializamos pygame

pygame.init()

# Muestro una ventana de 800x600
size = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Cambio el título de la ventana
pygame.display.set_caption('Juego BALL')

# Comenzamos el bucle del juego
run=True
while run:
    # Capturamos los eventos que se han producido
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Si el evento es salir de la ventana, terminamos
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: run = False
# Salgo de pygame
pygame.quit()
```

Si lo intento desde el terminal, aparece la ventana correctamente, pero si lo intento desde Visual Studio Code (que es el IDE que uso) entonces me da:

File "/media/douglas/9dab4c6f-dbf8-4250-a96c-da4ea7803616/Python/Bateria de ejemplos/prueba_pygame.py", line 2, in 
import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

El código corre incluso desde el terminal que muestra Visual Studio.

¿Por qué Visual Studio no puede reconocer pygame?

Comment: Instalaste pygame con la herramienta pip? Puedes verificar si está instalada abriendo una terminal y tecleando ``pip list`` te mostrará una lista de los paquetes instalados

Comment: Sí: la instaleé con pip y pip list me muestra el paquete. Por lo demás, corre desde el terminal. El problema lo tengo con Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Pareciera como si VS Code no pudiera seguir la trayectoria hasta pygame. Puede ser un problema de configuración, pero también estoy aprendiedo a manejar VS.

Comment: Cuando este tipo de fallos ocurren, siempre pregunto: tienes varias versiones de Python instaladas?

Comment: Efectivamente. También tengo instalado python2. ¡Cuál es la sugerencia en ese caso?

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví el problema a partir de la indicación de Dante. Resulta ser que tenía instalados pyhon 2, 3.8 y 3.9. El IDE de VS corre para 3.9 y yo había instalado pygame para 3.8. Acabo de cambiarlo a 3.9 y todo funciona perfectamente.